# Difference between $ F^\infty $ and $ F[x] $ in commutative linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$F[x]$ is defined as the subspace of $ F^\infty $ spanned by the vectors $ 1,x,x^2, ... $.

But any element $ f=(f_0, f_1, f_2, ... ) $ of $ F^\infty $ can be written as a linear combination of those vectors as follows

$ f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n x^n$

So are the two commutative linear algebras the same?

Comment: An infinite sum is a limit, and we need a topology to define limits. Infinite linear combinations doesn't make sense in linear algebra, only finite ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial ring only allows finite sums and the second one allows infinite sums as well, so they are not the same

Comment: In Hoffman and kunze, they define the F[x] to be the subspace spanned by an infinite set of vectors, namely  {$1,x,x^2,...$} so doesn't that include linear combinations which may be infinite sums? Or am I missing something?

Comment: By definition, a linear combination involves only finitely many vectors.